# What is a good outskirts area to stay in Washington DC

Tags: hotels, washington-dc

I am driving in to visit washingto DC. I was hoping to find a hotel along in an outskirt area somewhere with good access to the metro. This way cost are kept down and parking is much more likely to be free.

I am planning on taking the metro in, in the morning doing one massive day of as much of the tourist attractions as possible. Then heading back mid evening. I will be seeing Washington Monument, the a Smithsonian visit, Whitehouse, and Lincoln Memorial.

So to be concise.... and area close to metro, the short the ride the better, cheap hotel near metro (under $130), with free parking.

What are some good areas that fit this bill. I was considering Shady Grove or Rockville.

Comment: Found Silver Spring MD OK. There's a metro station.

Comment: In order for this question to be answerable in our format, you need to provide considerably greater detail as to what makes something "good," because every person's priorities and tradeoff thresholds between cost, comfort, and convenience will be different, and will also vary depending on how you plan to get around and what parts of town you are interested in visiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your daily schedule you may consider Hilton Washington DC North/Gaithersburg (J9/J7 express bus to Medical Center, works only peak time weekdays, or regular bus 55,61,58 to Shady Grove weekends),  or nearby Holiday Inn. My friends stayed in both and found both quite comfortable